# Deadlock in DB2 while updating a table using jdbc template

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to update a table for multiple rows in AS400 DB2. This query works fine when I test in work bench. When I use the same query from jdbc template, it creates dead lock and a lock is made on the table. What might be the issue here? Here is my code.

### QUERY

```
UPDATE <table name> SET status= 'CLOSED' WHERE PROCESSID IN ('ABC1243', 'DTH4666');
```

From using code.

```
public void updateStatus() {
    try { getJdbcTemplate().update("UPDATE <table name> SET status= 'CLOSED' WHERE PROCESSID IN ('ABC1243', 'DTH4666');}
    catch (Exception e) { logger.error(e); throw e; }       
}
```

Any ideas would be very useful for me.

Answer (score -1):

1.Is autocommit turned on or turned off on your database connection ?
 2. In DB2, there are chances of deadlock when you are firing a select query and 
    update query within same transaction.
 3. If the auto commit is turned off and you have fired a select query on the 
    table then try committing or rollback that transaction and then fire update 
    query. It should work.

Let me know in case if you are still facing above issue.

Comment: There is no select query. Its a plain update sql query and im the only developer working on it.

Comment: Have you checked if autocommit is turned on or turned off ? Try committing the transaction explicitly immediately after update execution.

Comment: I am having same problem here, do you have any solutions @Yakhoob